# Multiple insert Couchbase with node.js

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I'm trying to insert multiple records into couchbase, just now, I'm using the official node-couchbase driver.

```
var db = new couchbase.Connection({host: hostname, bucket: myBucket, password: pass}, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });

    var g = guid.raw()
    var a = [];

    for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
        new_beer = {
           "iteration" : i,
           "category": "North American Ale"
        }
        a.push(new_beer);
    }

    console.log(guid);
    db.set(g, a, function(err, result) {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Just in the insertion, only insert 1 element, I think that is because the g (the guid value is the same for all the registers. How I can insert these 100 registers in 1 only request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you should generate one guid per one item:

```
var docs = {};
for(var i=0; i<100; i++){
    var guid = guid.raw();
    docs[guid] = {
       "iteration" : i,
       "category": "North American Ale"
    }
}
```

Then you can use setMulti ([see docs here](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-node-client-1.2.1/Connection.html#setMulti)) to store all your data in one request.

```
db.setMulti(docs, {}, function(err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: Looks like setMulti had been removed on CouchBase Node 2 - http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.1.2/Bucket.html - Any alternative?

Comment: Answer no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Couchbase, NodeJs SDK does the batching internally, so there is not batching required and the batching multi API has been dropped.

Ref to NodeJS SDK 2.6 - [Batching Operations](https://docs.couchbase.com/nodejs-sdk/2.6/batching-operations.html) .The same applies for the future SDK 3 as well.

```
Node.js is an asynchronous language. Since the user is free to dispatch as many operations as they wish, which will be in parallel implicitly, there is no need to batch operations. In fact, if you schedule several asynchronous operations at the same time, then they will be performed at the same time, as the SDK effectively batches them internally.
```