# how to bulk insert with different key in Cochbase and node js

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I want to import MySQL data with some change in it. like join and json inside json.
I can insert one by one it. But it is taking lot of time.
I am doing this by following code. this code in for loop

```
config.bucket.insert('User|'+page._id, JSON.stringify(page), function(err, res) {

                    if (err) {
                     console.log('User|'+page._id+' operation failed  '+ err);
                      return;
                    }
                    console.log('User|'+page._id);

                });
```

So, I need.
How to do bulk insert with different key in Cochbase and node js ??

page._id is different key.I need it also in insert json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is what your are looking for:
https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/nodejs/bulkES6.js

```
function bulkUpdateAsyncPattern(){
  return new Promise(
      (resolve, reject) => {

          var completed = 0;
          var runFlag = false;
          var startTime = process.hrtime();

          // Function for modify one document, during bulk loop.  Notice,
          // this is only in scope for bulkUpdateAsyncPattern
          function modifyOne() {

              // First Check if the bulk pattern loop is done
              if (completed >= totalDocs && !runFlag) {
                  runFlag = true;
                  var time = process.hrtime(startTime);
                  console.log("====");
                  console.log("  Bulk Pattern Processing Loop Took: " + parseInt((time[0] * 1000) +
                          (time[1] / 1000000)) + " ms for: " + getMultiArray.length +
                      " items");
                  resolve();
              } else {
                  if (completed <= totalDocs) {

                      // Modify One Document
                      bucket.mutateIn('test' + completed, 0, 0)
                      .counter('rev', 1, false)
                      .execute( function(err, res) {
                          if (err) console.log("  Error modifying:", err.message);

                          // This will fire WHEN and only WHEN a callback is received.
                          if (res) {
                              // Increment completed count
                              completed++;

                              // Recursive call to modify
                              modifyOne();
                          }
                      });
                  }
              }
          }
          // The loop that sets up a "buffer" of queued operations
          // This sets up a number of requests always in the buffer waiting to execute
          for (var i = 0; i < opsGroup; ++i) {
              modifyOne();
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: btw, this is not a dup of [Multiple insert Couchbase with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817112/multiple-insert-couchbase-with-node-js) as the the API has changed.

Comment: I am doing it one by one but it take time if i have data more then 15K. it took 30 minutes.  is there another way ?? @Roi Katz

Comment: Did you try to batch it?

Comment: yes I try it. But I can not find how to insert as batch. @Roi Katz

Comment: Since NojeJS SDK version 2.x there is no setMulti anymore. the only way you can do it is to collect to docs and fire it as It described on top and in the dev-guide examples. basically this is what setMulti did - however it was not corresponding the unification of the sdks languages.
try to read on here as well - http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/batching-operations.html

Comment: hello @Roi Katz can you check my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740476/import-json-file-into-couchbase-using-cbdocloader