# Import JSON file into Couchbase using cbdocloader

Tags: json, node.js, import, couchbase

I use cbdocloader command to import  different json file into couchbase database. If my file content json like below

```
{"displayName":"Login","controller":"AppCtrl","action":"login","endpoint":"","group":0,"_type":"Permission"}
```

it is working fine.

But if my json content **_id** it will automatically exclude it from import I want to import my json like below

```
{"_id":"3dfd4bb0-aff4-11e6-8a96-8598a3ef40c4","displayName":"Login","controller":"AppCtrl","action":"login","endpoint":"","group":0,"_type":"Permission"}
```

How can I do this using **cbdocloader** ??

Comment: I get the solution I have changed a condition 
" if '_id' not in doc: "
in following file /opt/couchbase/lib/python/pump_json.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution I have changed a condition " if '_id' not in doc: " in following file /opt/couchbase/lib/python/pump_json.py

Answer (score 1):

Couchbase Server 4.5 treats `_id` in a different way:
https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-cli/blob/4.5.0/pump_json.py#L41-L62

Next version will use new docloader, which does not do it anymore. You can build it standalone: https://github.com/couchbase/docloader

```
export GOPATH=/tmp/gopath
mkdir -p $GOPATH
cd $GOPATH
go get github.com/couchbase/docloader/cmd/cbdocloader
```

It produces single static binary at

```
./bin/cbdocloader
```

Man page also located in the repository

```
man src/github.com/couchbase/docloader/man/man1/cbdocloader.1
```

You can see demo of this new docloader recorded on Connect 2016: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlK9R5Fqmpo

Comment: the steps assume that you have golang installed.You can install it with your package manager (apt/yum/dnf) or download directly (https://golang.org/dl/)

Comment: I have done go get. Now how to run my .zip file with cbdocloader ??

Comment: Man page I've referred has samples and describes all the options. Also have you seen the video?